# Wall socket tripping out when putting the two screws into the faceplate

Tags: wiring

I have put an outside socket on the wall with new wiring into the back of an inside socket.

It all works until I screw the two screws in to hold the faceplate on the inside wall. If I just leave it hanging there there is no problem. I'm in England.

Comment: Make sure to comment by hitting "add a comment" below your question or an answer.  Do not hit "Post your answer".  I gather you are familiar with "discussion forum" type things where posts are displayed in sequence.  That is not our format here; here *answers* are shuffled since each one can get a turn at the top.  Your thread won't thread!  So use comments.  You can always use comments on your own question; on other questions this requires some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Which country? As some regs limit the number of spurs you can have and if you did not check...

However, what is most likely is that one of the screws is pinching one of the wires inside the socket. Check and reposition them, but if there is damage to the conductor as well, you need to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

That very typically happens when either

- the wire is improperly positioned on a screw (e.g. too much naked wire sticking out; there should be essentially none), or
- a bare ground wire is flopping around and hitting a screw, and I understand in the UK you sleeve the bare ground wires so that's less of a problem, or
- the side screws are hitting the side of a metal junction box (this is worse when the screws are left "all the way out"; the factory often ships receptacles that way so they are ready to take wires, and then the screws are unused for some reason); or rarely
- tightening down the screws is pinching a wire into something metal; this is bad because now the wire must be replaced.

These are fixed by good technique, tightening down screws, and my preference, wrapping the receptacle with electrical tape so all the screws are covered.